# How to only get tweets with likes from Twitter API filtered Stream

Tags: node.js, twitter

I've built a node.js application that pulls tweets from a filtered stream, filtered by keywords and language. The rule I use:

`{ value: 'nintendo lang:en' }`

Keeping in mind the limit on how many tweets an app may pull, I'd like to narrow this filter down to tweets that have `public_metrics` with values of more than `n`. Is this possible? If so, how do I build the rule to manage this?

For example: I'd like to pull only tweets about nintendo that also have at least 10 likes or 5 retweets.

Answer (score 0):

You can't unless you pay for Enterprise API access. [Source](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/enterprise/decahose-api/overview/streaming-likes)